# Does subtraction circuit have a class like full or half Carry adder circuit in qiskit? one subtraction circuit code-example in qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

I need a subtraction circuit to calculate Laplacian in edge processing, but I didn't find any class in qiskit.Do I have to write the code myself?

Answer (score 0):

A full-adder circuit can be used for subtraction by using the fact that:
$$a - b = a + \neg b + 1$$
So, you need to invert the subtrahend, increment it by one, then do the addition as usual.
As an example, the following code uses [`VBERippleCarryAdder`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.VBERippleCarryAdder.html) to subtract 3 from 5:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit.library import VBERippleCarryAdder

num_state_qubits = 3
adder = VBERippleCarryAdder(num_state_qubits, name=' Adder ')
num_qubits = len(adder.qubits)

circ = QuantumCircuit(num_qubits)

# Five
circ.x([1, 3])

# Three
circ.x([num_state_qubits + 1, num_state_qubits + 2])

circ.barrier()
# Subtraction:
# 1) invert b:
circ.x(range(num_state_qubits + 1, 2 * num_state_qubits + 1))

# 2) add one (using carry-in)
circ.x(0)

# 3) do the addition
circ.append(adder, range(num_qubits))

circ.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

If you run this circuit the output will be: $001{\color{red}0\color{red}1\color{red}0}1011$

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Haw great, But in Laplacian's circuit, the subtrahend are not clear so that we can't calculate  its inverse because We are still in the middle of the circuit and we have not measured

Comment: It's simpler to temporarily bit flip the target rather than the offset, as this avoids having to deal with the +1 offset. `(a -= b) === (a ^= -1; a += b; a ^= -1)`.